# Custom section in App.Config, ConfigurationManager stops working

Tags: c#, .net, xml, app-config

I have created a console app in c# that reads information from App.config. if i add things in appSettings section, i can acces them and it works, but as soon as i add some custom sections i cant read anything from it. I am using ConfigurationManager, and i have the reference for it included.
My app config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
</startup>
<appSettings>
    <add key="overwriteBackupFiles" value="False"/>
    <add key="path" value="c:\temp"/>
</appSettings>
<ImageFormatsINeed>
  <add key="type1" value="width=180&#38;height=180"></add>
  <add key="type2" value="width=220&#38;height=220"></add>
  <add key="type3" value="width=500&#38;height=500"></add>
</ImageFormatsINeed>
</configuration>
```

and i am trying to acces those information like this:

```
string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["path"];

var settings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("ImageFormatsINeed");
```

When i didnt have the **ImageFormatsINeed** section i could get the path from AppSettings and it was working. But as soon as i added my **ImageFormatsINeed** section, everything stops working.

Now my question is how can i add custom sections in app.config that it will work, or should i just read my ImageInformation from some custom xml file or config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the tag <[configSections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/configsections-element-for-configuration)> at the top in your app.config, for this case you should use the type [AppSettingsSection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.appsettingssection?view=netframework-4.8)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section  name="ImageFormatsINeed" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection" />
    </configSections>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>        
    <appSettings>
        <add key="overwriteBackupFiles" value="False"/>
        <add key="path" value="c:\temp"/>
    </appSettings>
    <ImageFormatsINeed>
      <add key="type1" value="width=180&#38;height=180"></add>
      <add key="type2" value="width=220&#38;height=220"></add>
      <add key="type3" value="width=500&#38;height=500"></add>
    </ImageFormatsINeed>
    </configuration>
```

Then in your C# code:

```
NameValueCollection settings_section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("ImageFormatsINeed") as NameValueCollection;
Console.WriteLine(settings_section["type1"]);
```